# Java unresolved symbol

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm hoping this is a head-slapping, "duh", easy question to answer, but I'm new and can't figure it out.  I'm simply trying to define a HashMap and initialize it with "put" method, but my IDE (Intellij) gives me "can't resolve symbol" error on the "put".  I've created as simple an example as I can below.  Let the head-slapping begin.

```
package CSRLogin.NewAccount;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapTest {

    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myMap.put("A", "B");
}
```

Comment: Syntax errors are offtopic here, your problem is covered in any basic tutorial.

Comment: `myMap.put("A", "B");` is not in any code block.

Comment: So I think I figured this out  Use static initialization block (initializing is what I am trying to do in the first place).  And thanks Jeroen.  You're right, I'm sure that was covered in my class, but I still missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in some kind of code block such as a method or constructor:

```
public class MapTest {
    // Constructor
    public MapTest() {
        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myMap.put("A", "B");
    }

    // main-method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myMap.put("A", "B");
    }
}
```

If you wish to store the map as an instance variable you may do the following (if using a constructor):

```
public class MapTest {
    private Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Constructor
    public MapTest() {
        myMap.put("A", "B");
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to use a static variable to hold the data. Then you can also use a static initializer like this:

```
public class MapTest {
    static Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    {
        myMap.put("A", "B");
    }
}
```

Then you will have to access the map via the class name:

```
int size = MapTest.myMap.size();
```

See the following resources for more info:

- [Understanding class variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)
- [Basics about classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)